# Set value of property in main view controller from dynamically instantiated class (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am totally out of ideas on this... I've tried so many variations that I am dizzy...

I have a main UIViewController which, at the touch of a button, adds another UIViewController to one of its subviews. When the dynamic UIVC gets added, a property in the main UIVC is updated to hold a reference to it (called currentObject). This is working fine.

The problem I am having is that if I add another dynamic UIVC, the property holding the reference is initially updated correctly, but no matter what I try, I can't get the property to update when I touch the first dynamic UIVC. Everything I try to set "currentObject" from a dynamic UIVC gives me an "unrecognized selector sent to class" error and then bails.

I'm holding off from putting code into this post at first. Not sure what I would post that would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Updated:

in DynamicModuleViewController.h:

```
@interface DynamicModuleViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>{

DynamicModule *currentObject;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) DynamicModule *currentObject;
```

in DynamicModuleViewController.m:

```
@implementation DynamicModuleViewController

@synthesize currentObject;

-(void)addObject:(id)sender
{
DynamicModule *dm = [[DynamicModule alloc]init];
// positioning and PanGesture recognition code to allow dragging of module
currentObject = dm;
[mainView addSubview:currentObject.view];
}

@end
```

when added this way, from a button tap, it works fine.

Once more DynamicModules are instantiated, I need to update currentObject with the DynamicModule that was tapped last.

Comment: Helpful code to add: `currentObject` in main UIVC, the method that creates an error, the error itself.

Comment: I guess I am going to have to start the whole thing from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

> adds another UIViewController to one of its subviews

First of all this is a red flag to me. Adding a UIViewController's view as a subview is almost always the wrong way to manage a view hierarchy and a common mistake in iOS apps. Please see http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/ so I can stay on topic and avoid repeating myself.

> currentObject = dm;

This sets the ivar backing your `currentObject` property directly. You are leaking the previous value of `currentObject`. You don't appear to be removing the previous `currentObject`'s view from `mainView`. I suspect you are setting the `currentObject` to an autoreleased object, failing to retain it because you bypassed your setter, and eventually try to send a message to the released object resulting in either an "unrecognized selector" error as your message reaches whatever other object now occupies that memory address or a BAD_ACCESS error as you try to reference an object which no longer exists.

`self.currentObject = foo` is equivalent to `[self setCurrentObject:foo]` and is probably what you intended.

Comment: Thanks, Jonah. I'll be taking another look at this after work and get back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the delegate pattern?